# Raspberry Pi docker installation, easy_install: command not found

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, docker

I am trying to install docker on my Raspberry Pi and can't seem to get this to work.

I've tried few solutions suggested here (including installing python-setuptools) but none seem to work.

Any ideas how to fix this?

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo apt-get -y install python-setuptools && sudo easy_install pip  && sudo pip install docker-compose~=1.23.0 

Reading package lists... Done 

Building dependency tree Reading state information... Done 

python-setuptools is already the newest version (40.8.0-1). 

0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded. 

sudo: easy_install: command not found
```

Answer (score 2):

Unless you need `easy_install` for something else, you might be better off installing `pip` from the system package manager:

```
apt install python-pip
```

or

```
apt install python3-pip
```

if you want to use Python 3